# Database Project; Cross-Database Intellisense

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2010, database-project

I've been trying to move all my SQL databases to VS 2010 SQL Server 2008 database projects this weekend and have noticed that Intellisense is messed up when setting up cross-database relationships. Note: Both database projects are in the same solution.

Here's what I want to do (with Intellisense offline so I make sure I don't goof up..):

```
--2 Databases (1) DB_Main which references (2) DB_Support (both on the same SQL instance)
--using DB_Main

Select Column1, Column2, Column3
From DB_Support.dbo.ExampleTable WITH (nolock)
```

...is that so much to ask?

Anyways it seems like the code all compiles fine when typing it out w/o the Intellisense support, but that takes a lot longer and you have to build to see if you goofed... I read [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vstsdb/thread/6ff99948-b33b-4ae2-9093-034a6df9c067/) that it works "not like you would expect" where the following seems to be valid:

```
--Again using DB_Main

Select Column1, Column2, Column3
From dbo.ExampleTable WITH (nolock)
```

... but ***< insert expletive here >***, DB_Main.dbo.ExampleTable doesn't exist!!!, and I tested it and it will deploy that way, unless I did something wrong, which is possible, I've had all of 1 day's experience with all this...

Anyways, I have this cross-database issue in several of the instances I manage/develop so any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I wondered if there are meanwhioe any solutions / fixs for this behaviour?

I figured out the same and can't believe it.

Actually my compiler won't allow me to add a "Table1" object into a database project (B) that references another database project (A) having a Table1 object as well because the objects of (A) are loaded into the schema collection of (B). This is nonsense...!

Maybe there is some new progress with this iddue I did not find so far..:?